# Submitting Ubuntu Touch Scope

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-touch

I have a problem trying to upload an Ubuntu Scope to the store. When I upload the *.click file, I get the following error:

> "The uploaded package name (ba-unsa-etf) does not use your namespace
>   (ba-unsa-etf)"

What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-ubuntu-com/+bug/1408644), your namespace should be now named:

> appname.devname

The store has been updated last month (See [comment #9](https://bugs.launchpad.net/developer-ubuntu-com/+bug/1408644/comments/9)) to support this new format.

Comment: But I can't use a dot in the namespace name: "Lower-case letters, numbers or hyphens allowed only."

Answer (score 0):

Edit your 'manifest.json' and change app name like

**`myapp-myname.namespace`**

In sort

**`<app-name>.<namespace>`**